# How to configure HTML form to work with django models?

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to configure `HTML form`to work with `Django Models` rather than using built-in `Forms` in the framework. I have made the form using `Html` below and have pasted the code for `Model`, `View` and `Urls.py`. The problem is when I click the `submit` button, it doesn't perform any action. I am able to view the form but it doesn't serves the purpose. I know the question is very lame, but how would configure the HTML to work with the django model so that the data can be saved to the database?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body style="font-family:Courier New">
    <h1>Add / Edit Book</h1>
    <hr/>
    <form id="formHook" action="/istreetapp/addbook" method="post">
        <p style="font-family:Courier New">Name <input type="text" placeholder="Name of the book"></input></p>
        <p style="font-family:Courier New">Author <input type="text" placeholder="Author of the book"></input></p>
        <p style="font-family:Courier New"> Status
            <select>
                <option value="Read">Read</option>
                <option value="Unread">Unread</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    <input type="submit" id="booksubmit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**View**

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from istreetapp.models import bookInfo
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
    booklist = bookInfo.objects.all().order_by('Author')[:10]
    temp = loader.get_template('app/index.html')
    contxt = Context({
        'booklist' : booklist,
    })
return HttpResponse(temp.render(contxt))
```

**Model**

```
from django.db import models

class bookInfo(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Status = models.IntegerField(default=0) # status is 1 if book has been read

def addbook(request, Name, Author):
    book = bookInfo(Name = Name, Author=Author)
    book.save
    return render(request, 'templates/index.html', {'Name': Name, 'Author': Author})
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^addbook/$', 'addbook'),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to define **name** in each of your input

```
<form id="formHook" action="/addbook/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p style="font-family:Courier New">
        Name <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name of the book"></input>
    </p>

    <p style="font-family:Courier New">
        Author <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Author of the book"></input>
    </p>

    <p style="font-family:Courier New"> 
        Status
        <select name="status">
            <option value="Read">Read</option>
            <option value="Unread">Unread</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" id="booksubmit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

Your **addbook must be in the views.py** not in your models.py. 
You don't have to define templates/index.html in your render, it is understood in your settings

```
def addbook(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        author = request.POST['author']
        bookInfo.objects.create(Name = name, Author=author)
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'Name': name, 'Author': author})
```

**main urlconf**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'project_name.views.index'),
    url(r'^addbook/$', 'project_name.views.addbook'),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: i have added the `urlpatterns` just as you told, but as i click the submit the data, the url is not able to find `addbook` view. is there any other way of adding `url` into `form' action?

Comment: My urls.py is in the project directory. I used this but still the `urlpatterns` issue is there. I tried concatenating a new `urlpatterns` with the original one. It still doesn't works.

Comment: @mozart Ok I updated my answer sorry I forgot to put views in the url that's why it's not working

Comment: I have already tried that way. Should I add a new template `addbook`?

Comment: much better so that you will not be able to put url in the form

Comment: Thank you. :) There was some problem at my side. Silly me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add name attributes to your html form then process the form submission in the view. Something like -

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

def book_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        author = request.POST['author']
        book = BookInfo(name=name, author=author)
        if book.is_valid():
            book.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('your_redirect_url')
    else:
        return render(request, 'your_form_page.html')
```

Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) on the request.POST dictionary.

However you really would be better off doing this with a django ModelForm -

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BookInfo # I know you've called it bookInfo, but it should be BookInfo
```

then in your view -

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

def book_view(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        book = get_object_or_404(BookInfo, pk=pk)
    else:
        book = BookInfo()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST, instance=book)
        if form.is_valid():
            book = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks_page')
    else:
        form = BookForm(instance=book)
    return render(request, 'your_form_page.html', {'form': form)
```

And `your_form_page.html` can be as simple as -

```
<form action="{% url book_view %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/) on working with forms.

Comment: it now says: 'url' requires a non-empty first argument. What does that mean?

Comment: It's an error with the {% url book_view %} tag. Read up on the function - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

Comment: You could replace it with the actual url to make it work but you shouldn't be using hardcoded url's - do read up on the reverse function to get an understanding of how it works (you'll need to make changes to your url.conf).