# How to access all the entries in MySQL table in Django View?

Tags: mysql, django

I am designing a Web Application using Django Framework. I have written the `model` code, `urls.py` and `view` code which can be seen [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172903/how-to-configure-html-form-to-work-with-django-models).

I have added some data into the database `table`. But when I try to access the object using the code below, it just shows `bookInfo objects` five times. I don't think I am successful enough in pulling the data from the database. Kindly help.

**View**

```
def showbooks(request):
    booklist = bookInfo.objects.order_by('Name')[:10]
    output = ','.join([str(id) for id in booklist])
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are successful in pulling the data. It is just that `booklist` contains objects, not numeric ids. You can add `__unicode__` method to you class `BookInfo` that is supposed to return a string representation of the object (probably book name in this case). This method is going to be invoked when `str()` is applied. You can find more info about `__unicode__` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through the object list, you just need to reference the column/attribute you want:

```
output = ','.join([obj.id for obj in booklist])
```

Alternatively you can more more finely craft you original db call, then the iterable you use will work. In this case we'll pull out a list of the 'id' attribute.

```
booklist = bookInfo.objects.order_by('Name').values_list('id', flat=True)[:10]
output = ','.join([id for id in booklist])
```